# Return request then do calculations django

Tags: django

I have a form, and I need to do some calculations (writing to a database, extract data etc. etc.) which takes some time.

I want to do these calculation in the background i.e *after* the return.
Right now the user are waiting for `long_taking_calculation_function` to finish before `return redirect("my_template")` which is not very userfriendly - is there a way to do it the other way round?

```py
def add_data(request):
    user = request.user
    instance = MyModel(user=user)
    form = MyModel_form(request.POST,instance = instance)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do some calculations
            long_taking_calculation_function()

            return redirect("my_template")


    return render(request, "my_app/my_template.html")
```

Comment: have a look on this https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/index.html

Comment: You can also use https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, I find it easier then celery and more suitable  for some projects.

Comment: Might always want to look into the newer async support from recent Django versions. Read the documents as there are few gotchas. See https://www.valentinog.com/blog/django-q/#how-about-asynchronous-django for quick overview. I think something design for the background tasks (like celery, channels, django-background-tasks) is likely what you are after.